# Opposite of Split in PowerShell (Non-cmdlet)

Tags: powershell

What is the opposite function of the following?

```
    $tmp = $domain.split(".")
```

In other words, how do I transfer an array to a string. I've heard of "join", but I can't get it to work.

Non-cmdlet, non-quest, this has to work with PowerShell v1 and all of the older systems!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = [string]::join(".", $array)
```

Comment: This one has the green check mark, but see also jon Z's answer.

Answer (score 15):

There's a join operator in Powershell:

```
$tmp -join "."
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the Join operator (introduced in v2) and the .NET Join method, you can also change the value of the special variable [$OFS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/07/15/what-is-ofs.aspx) (Ouptut Field Seperator) to a dot (the default value is a space) and enclose tmp in quotes:

```
PS> $tmp = "foo.domain.com".split(".")
PS> & {$ofs='.';"$tmp"}
foo.domain.com
```

In the above example I changed $OFS in a script block to prevent it from changing in the global scope (scriptblocks creates nested scope)

Comment: Ah Shay, I've read alot of your tutorials, and I must say you do not disappoint! Keep up the good work man. - On this subject I'm surprised that there is no simple function like the "implode()" function of PHP. What a world we live in eh.

Comment: Thanks @KarlMorrison, I'm not familiar with the Implode function but you can create one: function implode($array,$delimiter) { $array -join $delimiter }; implode $tmp '.'

Comment: Script blocks do NOT create nested scope.

Comment: @Nacht Double check yourself.

Comment: what i mean is that it's the ampersand that creates separate scope, since you can run script blocks with a `.` and it would run in the same scope. most importantly, script blocks for foreach and while do not run in a separate scope. maybe that's because they're probably not technically script blocks... but still that's the thing that it's easy to get burned on